# Jquery UI sortable Change not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui

I have this code for initilazing my sortable ul, but both methods only render 1 item of the list and not the whole of it, with the `stop` event everything is fine, but I need to use the change event, what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

[API JQUERY SORTABLE](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable)

```
 $( "#sortable-ul" ).sortable({
    scroll: true,
    items: "> li",
    change: function() {
        console.log($("#sortable-ul").sortable("toArray"));
        console.log($("#sortable-ul").sortable("serialize"));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$( "#sortable-ul" ).sortable({
    scroll: true,
    items: "> li",
    update: function() {
        console.log($("#sortable-ul").sortable("toArray"));
        console.log($("#sortable-ul").sortable("serialize"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Worked for me, but is this not supposed to do the same?